# What is the difference between stating the events and stating the probability of events?

Tags: probability

I have this question in class, and I don't understand the difference between A and B.

> A survey was performed by a local pharmacy investigating the medication of customers with a common cold. Of the 60 customs surveyed, 13 stated they experienced a runny nose, 23 stated they experienced a sore throat and 10 reported experiencing both a runny nose and a sore throat.
>   a State the events for the scenario
>   b A customer is picked at random from this survey. What is the probability that the selected customer:
>   i has a runny nose,
>   ii does not have a runny nose, but has a sore throat,
>   iii has a runny nose or a sore throat, but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are the outcomes: if you throw a six-faced dice, the events are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, if you throw a coin, the events are $\{$head,tail$\}$. The probability of an event is instead a number with such and such properties: suppose the dice and the coin balanced, so in the first example $P(1)=P(2)=\ldots=P(6)= 1/6$, in the second example $P(\text{tail}) = P(\text{head}) = 1/2$.

For your exercise: call $S$ the "sore throat", $R$ the "runny nose". The events are then $\{S$ and $R$, only $S$, only $R$, no $S$ and no $R$}. Be careful when you calculate the probabilities: $P(R) = P((S \text{ and } R) \text{ or } (\text{only} R)) = P(S \text{ and } R) + P(\text{only} R)$.

Edit to better explain "events": you have a set of results, like $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but then you want to know something like "the probability to be even" and calculate something like $P(\text{even}) = P(\{2,4,6\})=P(2)+P(4)+P(6)= 1/2$. The probability is not a function from $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but (in the discrete case) from the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (more generally, you have to talk about $\sigma$-algebras...).

Comment: How do I go about answer ii and iii of question b?

For ii, I know that it is the intersection of those who don't have a runny nose but do have a sore throat, but how do I go about using their probabilities?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Zj2YpZV) here is the event that I deduced from it, but how do I plug in the values?

Comment: In general events are not outcomes. Outcomes are elements of outcome/sample space mostly denoted as $\Omega$ and events are (measurable) subsets of $\Omega$. Often it happens that for every outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ the singleton $\{\omega\}$ is an event. In the example of a six-sided die the set of outcomes can be taken to be $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and the collection of events is $\wp(\Omega)$. In your edit you go into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Think about events as possible outcomes of some experiment. A survey is a kind of an experiment. In the example you brought, the possible outcomes are runny nose, and sore throat. There may be of course other possible outcomes, but in your case they are not specified, so that you can safely assume that the events, i.e. possible outcomes are just 1. runny nose, and 2. sore throat. Observe that in specifying the possible outcomes (aka possible events) nothing is said about the probabilities of these possible outcomes. A specification of the probabilities requires an assignment of numbers to the possible outcomes. For each possible outcome, there corresponds some number in the interval $[0,1]$, which tells you the probability for that possible outcome to occur. To summarize: Specification of events means listing out the possible outcomes, and specification of probabilities means assigning to each possible outcome its probability. In particular, you must first specify the outcomes, and only then their probabilities.

Comment: For completeness, isn't {nothing} also an event in this survey?

Comment: That's exactly the answer I needed! So you would denote the probability of events like P("runny nose") = 13/60

How do you denote the events for the scenario?

Comment: @dcolazin is that also called the sample space?

Comment: @OskarSherrah exactly; from my point of view, here asking for the "events" is asking for the sample space

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help @dcolazin